# Enlaces "<a>" se abren automáticamente en Microsoft edge con live server

Tags: css, html5, edge, vscode-live-server

Bajo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      h1{
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(36, 36, 118);
      }
      a{
        color: #CC0000;
      }
      
      a:hover{
        background-color: #CC0000;
        color: #FFF;
      }
      a:visited{
        color: #CCC;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>APLICANDO ESTILO A ENLACES</h1>
    <a href="#1">Enlace número 1</a>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="#2">Enlace número 2</a>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="#3">Enlace número 3</a>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="#4">Enlace número 4</a>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="#5">Enlace número 5</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Me he dado cuenta de que al abrir el archivo con live server en microsoft edge, no funciona correctamente. Si lo abro como archivo, funciona normal.

Con live server muestra al principio los enlaces normal, pero cuando le doy a uno, no le cambia el color, entonces refresco la pagina y me muestra como si hubiera abierto todos los enlaces.

Esto en chrome no me ocurre, en chrome me funciona perfectamente todo.

Me gustaría saber si es porque hay algún tipo de conflicto entre edge y live server o es que tengo algo mal dentro del código.

Comment: Los enlaces marcados como visited son por página visitada. Cuando tienes un enlace tipo "#4" lo que dices es que estás visitando tu misma página, pero en otra sección, pero al final de cuentas la página ya se abrió. Tendrías que tener un enlace 4.html para que no lo tome como que visitó esa página.